# "jquery.min.map not found" ao debugar Cordova para iOS

Tags: apache-cordova

Meu projeto abre sem erros no Browser e na WebView do Android. Só na WebView do iOS (pelo safari developer tools) está acusando somente este erro.

```
file:///Users/rop/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E4F8BD7E-8AA1-40F4-91F1-4F8EACD6449F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F3961589-52D6-429E-8551-C7FAEB63110F/meuApp.app/www/lib/jquery.min.map
```